# Use a variable as an argument in a Python function

Tags: python

I have a Python time series modeling program where the user sets conditions, or variables, they want to use. One of the variables they set is 'cadence', which takes the values of 'days', 'weeks', 'months', etc. I want to then use this variable in Pandas' `DateOffset` function to offset dates accordingly. How can I do this?

Below is an example of what I want, though this example does not work. In the example `new_d` would take the value of '2019-01-15'.

```
import pandas as pd
cadence = 'weeks'
d = pd.Timestamp('2019-01-01')
new_d = d + pd.DateOffset(cadence=2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
import pandas as pd
cadence = 'weeks'
d = pd.Timestamp('2019-01-01')
new_d = d + pd.DateOffset(**{cadence:2})
new_d
# Timestamp('2019-01-15 00:00:00')
```